# I am getting Duplicate values when i try to update Access table records using VB6

Tags: vb6

im still a beginner in vb6 id love to learn and improve, iv been stuck for about a week trying to solve this problem. Any advice or help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

My code was meant to do three things. First is to check if the table has null values and create a new record with a primary that is EnrolmentID, Second it is to update that value when it matches with a previous records primary key. And lastly it is to create a new record if its primary key doesn't match with any of the current records.

Okay here is the thing, when i add new values, new records are created(thats fine), But when i try to update a current record. It only updates the FIRST record in the table and not The Second or any other record below it. If i update any of the records after the first
it DUPLICATES that record.

I know this because i keep getting this error:

The changes you requested to the table were not successful because they would create duplicate values in the index, field...

And it started showing up when i removed an Auto-Increment field from the table and 
made the EnrolmentID a primary key instead. I did this because it kept showing duplicated
records.

Here is my code:

```
'Checks of the table has a null value then adds a new record

If Combo1.Text = "Boarding Fee Term One" And Text33.Text <> "0.00" Then

If lol.RecordCount = 0 Then                                        
lol.AddNew                                                      
    lol.Fields("EnrolmentID") = frmStudentFees.AcctNo           
    lol.Fields("StudentID") = frmStudentFees.txtstudID.Text
    lol.Fields("TransDate") = Date
    lol.Fields("CashierCompletename") = CurrentUser.FullName
    lol.Fields("TermOne") = Text33.Text
    sumBOne = (boardingfee) - (Text33.Text)
    lol.Fields("BalanceOne") = sumBOne
lol.Update
Else

'Checks if ID matches any of the existing records and updates                                                                                                                                                                       
If lol.Fields("EnrolmentID") = frmStudentFees.AcctNo Then

    If IsNull(lol.Fields("TermOne")) Then
    GetBOne = 0
    Else
    GetBOne = lol.Fields("TermOne")
    End If

    SumOf1 = (GetBOne) + (Text33.Text)
    sumBOne = (boardingfee) - (SumOf1)

    lol.Fields("EnrolmentID") = frmStudentFees.AcctNo
    lol.Fields("StudentID") = frmStudentFees.txtstudID.Text
    lol.Fields("TransDate") = Date
    lol.Fields("CashierCompletename") = CurrentUser.FullName
    lol.Fields("TermOne") = SumOf1

    lol.Fields("BalanceOne") = sumBOne
    lol.Update

'Checks if there are any existing records that match the ID nun are available creates
'a new record.
ElseIf Not lol.Fields("EnrolmentID") = frmStudentFees.AcctNo Then

lol.addnew
    lol.Fields("EnrolmentID") = frmStudentFees.AcctNo            
    lol.Fields("StudentID") = frmStudentFees.txtstudID.Text
    lol.Fields("TransDate") = Date
    lol.Fields("CashierCompletename") = CurrentUser.FullName
    lol.Fields("TermOne") = Text33.Text
    sumBOne = boardingfee - Text33
    lol.Fields("BalanceOne") = sumBOne
lol.Update

 End If

 End If
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a 'select' sql query to select the record in the table with the student ID you're interested in 'frmStudentFees.AcctNo'

```
dim s1 as string 
s1 = "select from tablename where enrolmentid = '" & frmStudentFees.AcctNo & "'"
dim rs as recordset 
set rs = db.openrecordset(s1)
if rs.bof <> true or myrec.eof <> true then
   rs.movefirst
   rs.edit

      lol.Fields("TermOne") = SumOf1
      'etc

   rs.update

else
   rs.addnew

      lol.Fields("TermOne") = SumOf1
      'etc

   rs.update
end if
```

Comment: okay iv added the code you suggested but i get an error "Object or With Block variable not set" and i want to post my code for you to set.

Comment: Just above the line in your code 'set rs =..', you need to 'set' the database object variable, as in 'set db = opendatabase(pathtodatabase)'

Comment: ooowww let me do that ill keep you posted

Comment: Dude id like to say THANK YOU!!! I was able to use your correction and  re edit my code. And IT works!!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As Recordset

strTwo = "Select * From tblPayedAmount"

strOne = "Select * From tblPayedAmount where enrolmentid = '" & frmStudentFees.AcctNo &"'"

lol.Open strTwo, con, 2, 3

Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strOne) '<<------THE ERROR HIGHLIGNTS THIS LINE

If Combo1.Text = "Boarding Fee Term One" And Text33.Text <> "0.00" Then

If lol.RecordCount = 0 Then                    
lol.AddNew                                                      
    lol.Fields("EnrolmentID") = frmStudentFees.AcctNo          
    lol.Fields("StudentID") = frmStudentFees.txtstudID.Text
    lol.Fields("TransDate") = Date
    lol.Fields("CashierCompletename") = CurrentUser.FullName
    lol.Fields("TermOne") = Text33.Text
    sumBOne = (boardingfee) - (Text33.Text)
    lol.Fields("BalanceOne") = sumBOne
lol.Update
Else

If rs.BOF <> True Or lol.EOF <> True Then

   rs.MoveFirst
   rs.Edit

    If IsNull(lol.Fields("TermOne")) Then
    GetBOne = 0
    Else
    GetBOne = lol.Fields("TermOne")
    End If

    SumOf1 = (GetBOne) + Val(Text33.Text)
    sumBOne = (boardingfee) - (SumOf1)


    lol.Fields("EnrolmentID") = frmStudentFees.AcctNo
    lol.Fields("StudentID") = frmStudentFees.txtstudID.Text
    lol.Fields("TransDate") = Date
    lol.Fields("CashierCompletename") = CurrentUser.FullName
    lol.Fields("TermOne") = SumOf1

    lol.Fields("BalanceOne") = sumBOne

    rs.Update


Else

    rs.AddNew

    lol.Fields("EnrolmentID") = frmStudentFees.AcctNo             '   new field in the table.
    lol.Fields("StudentID") = frmStudentFees.txtstudID.Text
    lol.Fields("TransDate") = Date
    lol.Fields("CashierCompletename") = CurrentUser.FullName
    lol.Fields("TermOne") = Text33.Text
    sumBOne = boardingfee - Text33
    lol.Fields("BalanceOne") = sumBOne

    rs.Update

  End If

 End If
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

```
strOne = "Select * From tblPayedAmount Where enrolmentid = '" & frmStudentFees.AcctNo &"'"

lol.Open strOne, con, 2, 3 

If Combo1.Text = "Boarding Fee Term One" And Text33.Text <> "0.00" Then

If lol.RecordCount = 0 Then 

lol.AddNew                                                      
lol.Fields("EnrolmentID") = frmStudentFees.AcctNo          
lol.Fields("StudentID") = frmStudentFees.txtstudID.Text
lol.Fields("TransDate") = Date
lol.Fields("CashierCompletename") = CurrentUser.FullName
lol.Fields("TermOne") = Text33.Text
sumBOne = (boardingfee) - (Text33.Text)
lol.Fields("BalanceOne") = sumBOne
lol.Update

Else

If lol.BOF <> True Or lol.EOF <> True Then

lol.MoveFirst


If IsNull(lol.Fields("TermOne")) Then
GetBOne = 0
Else
GetBOne = lol.Fields("TermOne")
End If

SumOf1 = (GetBOne) + Val(Text33.Text)
sumBOne = (boardingfee) - (SumOf1)


lol.Fields("EnrolmentID") = frmStudentFees.AcctNo
lol.Fields("StudentID") = frmStudentFees.txtstudID.Text
lol.Fields("TransDate") = Date
lol.Fields("CashierCompletename") = CurrentUser.FullName
lol.Fields("TermOne") = SumOf1

lol.Fields("BalanceOne") = sumBOne

lol.Update


Else

lol.AddNew

lol.Fields("EnrolmentID") = frmStudentFees.AcctNo             'new field in the table.
lol.Fields("StudentID") = frmStudentFees.txtstudID.Text
lol.Fields("TransDate") = Date
lol.Fields("CashierCompletename") = CurrentUser.FullName
lol.Fields("TermOne") = Text33.Text
sumBOne = boardingfee - Text33
lol.Fields("BalanceOne") = sumBOne

lol.Update

End If

End If
End If
```